# Puntero a Estructuras

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy tomando un curso de C++ y llegue al modulo de puntero con estructuras y al intentar hacer el ejercicio me sale unos errores y no entiendo porque, he buscado varias referencias y no lo puedo resolver, espero que puedan ayudarme

```
//Punteros a Estructuras

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct persona {
    char nombre[50];
    int edad;
}persona, *puntero = &persona;

void getData() {
    cout << "Ingrese su nombre: " << endl;
    cin.getline(puntero -> nombre, 50, '\n');

    cout << "\nIngrese su edad: " << endl;
    cin >> puntero->edad;
}

void imprimir(persona* puntero) {
    cout << "Su nombre es: " << puntero->nombre;
    cout << "Su Edad es: " << puntero->edad;
}

int main() {
    getData();
    imprimir(puntero);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Errores en el compilador]

[image: Parde donde sale el error]

Comment: Por favor, los detalles importantes (como los mensajes de eror) han de ir **como texto**. Te sugiero consultar [¿ Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la declaración de la estructura:

```
struct persona {
    char nombre[50];
    int edad;
}persona, *puntero = &persona;
```

En C++ las  variables se declaran  anteponiendo el tipo al nombre  de la  variable. Por ejemplo: int  numero,  *pnumero, es una variable de  tipo entera  y un puntero a un entero. Siguiendo ese ejemplo, vamos a  declarar tu estructura  persona:

```
struct persona{
    char nombre[50];
    int edad;
} *puntero;
```

Como la estructura se llama persona no es necesario definir una variable con ese nombre.

Si quieres que imprimir  reciba un puntero a la struct  persona tienes  que hacerlo asi:

```
void imprimir(struct persona  * ptrPersona) {
    cout << "Su nombre es: " << ptrPersona->nombre;
    cout << "Su Edad es: " << ptrPersona->edad;
}
```

luego debes llamar a imprimir:

```
int main() {



/// Tienes que asignar al puntero el area del struct
     puntero =  new  struct persona;

    getData();
    imprimir(puntero);

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```